# How does Java Scanner work in this situation?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a task.
Input data in the console.
The first line contains elements of the list. The second line contains the number of swaps. Then follow the lines with descriptions of the swaps. Each line contains two numbers: indexes of swapped elements.

```
Example:
Input:
1 2 3 4 5 6
2
0 1
3 5
Output: 2 1 3 6 5 4
```

The problem is how to read 2 numbers properly. scanner.nextInt() only reads 1 int. The Idea is to read them as String, then split in the array and pass to the swap method as integers. It doesn’t work properly.

```
   import java.util.*;

    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = scanner.nextLine();
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
          int swapNum = scanner.nextInt();
           
          for (int i = 0; i < swapNum; i++) {
              scanner.nextLine();
              String[] sw = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
              int f = Integer.parseInt(sw[0]);
              int s = Integer.parseInt(sw[1]);
              Collections.swap(list, f, s);
               
          }
          for (String item : list) {
                System.out.print(item + " ");
            }
        }   
    }
```

I looked at the answer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < swapNum; i++) {       
 Collections.swap(list, scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());         
}
```

Why it doesn’t work properly in my solution?
Why in the answer does the line read two integers properly?

Comment: Inside your for loop you are skipping every second line by calling `scanner.nextLine()` twice.

Comment: Unrelated: use meaningful variable names that tell the reader something. f and s ... say nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner.nextLine() -> will read all remaining line and return it. After that it will not be available in the scanner any more.

Scanner.nextInt() -> will read next integer and consume it. After that it will not be available in the scanner any more.

In your solution you read twice a line.

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = scanner.nextLine(); <-- you read first line
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
          int swapNum = scanner.nextInt();  <-- you read first int of second line but you have not consumed all the line. So next time you will read again from second line


for (int i = 0; i < swapNum; i++) {
                      scanner.nextLine(); <-- Once you read it here it is consumed
                      String[] sw = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");  <---here it will read
        the next line the second time you call it, not the same result as you had in the 
        previous line of code. 
    The result of previous line of code is now gone! You have skipped this line.
                      int f = Integer.parseInt(sw[0]);
                      int s = Integer.parseInt(sw[1]);
                      Collections.swap(list, f, s);
                       
                  }
```

Try with

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = scanner.nextLine();
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
          int swapNum = scanner.nextInt();
          scanner.nextLine();

     for (int i = 0; i < swapNum; i++) {
              String readedLine = scanner.nextLine(); 
              String[] sw = readedLine.split(" "); 
              int f = Integer.parseInt(sw[0]);
              int s = Integer.parseInt(sw[1]);
              Collections.swap(list, f, s);
               
          }
```

Or even better Why you don't try to clean read every line with nextLine() and make everything you want with it instead of using nextInt() here and there?

```
String inputLine = scaner.next(); //will read all the line
    
    String[] numbersAsStrings = inputLine.split("\\s+"); //split input line with empty space
    List<Integer> numbersAsInt = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(numbersAsStrings).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).forEach(numbersAsInt::add);//collect all integers
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution with streams. But I can't use them yet. 
If I use " String readedLine = scanner.nextLine(); " or delete the line, it throws exception:
" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" "

Comment: directly after int swapNum = scanner.nextInt(); add scanner.nextLine() to consume the line that you have read with nextInt(). Be careful put scanner.nextLine() just after int swapNum and before the for loop.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did it wrong - instead of putting scanner.nextLine() before scanInt(), I put it into for loop.

Comment: I don't understand why scanner.nextInt() in Collections.swap(lst, scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt()) can read 2 numbers in the row. If I try to use scanner.nextInt() it will take only the first int.

Comment: Each time you call scanner.nextInt() it reads the first integer it finds and then its out of the scanner. Scanner forgot about what you have read. Next time you call scanner.nextInt() it reads the next integer it finds. So by calling scanner.nextInt() first time it reads the first integer of the line. Second time of scanner.nextInt() it reads the second integer of the line. Please read scanner class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after you input number of swaps, the scanner, using `nextInt()` method, takes only part of the line and parses it to integer. Rest of this line is consumed by `scanner.nextLine()` in your loop which happens to be empty. That's why u are getting an error. Quick workaround would be to consume whole line and parse it to number of swaps:

```
int swapNum = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Also as @Turamarth mentioned, remove first line in your loop as it will prompt your input twice:

```
scanner.nextLine(); <- REMOVE
String[] sw = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I will delete the line, it throws exception: " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" "

Comment: @AlexJ Have you changed that lane where you assign `swapNum` to the one I posted aswell?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No I didn't :)

Comment: Try using it. I've compiled the code in my environment and it worked.